# Applying for Parent Super visa before landing in Canada with a PR

Tags: canada, resident-permit, dependent-visa, express-entry

I have received a job offer in Canada and am already in express entry pool. I need to take my mother with me as she is widowed and old. Is it possible to apply for her super visa along with my application? Or do I have to go to Canada and then apply? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: For clarity, under which of the Express Entry programs are you applying?

Comment: Federal skilled worker program. Sorry I missed to mention this

Answer (score 1):

From CIC:

[Who is eligible for a parent and grandparent super visa?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=429&top=16)

> To be eligible for the super visa, applicants must be the parents and
>   grandparents of Canadian citizens or permanent residents.

By definition, you are not a permanent resident until you land as a permanent resident. So you have two options:

1. Land as a permanent resident and then apply for super visa (There may be additional requirements for this)
2. Apply for a regular visitor visa for your mother and bring her in with you when you land.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know how long it would take before I can sponsor her with my PR there?

Comment: You need to be a permanent resident to sponsor and meet proof of income requirements. You can check your eligibility [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/family-sponsorship/sponsor-parents-grandparents/eligibility.html)

Comment: that is for them becoming a permanent resident right? because its asking proof of fund for 3 years!

Comment: No. That is the requirement for sponsoring parents. See the page title [How much income do I need to sponsor my parents and grandparents?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1445&top=14)

Comment: but here it has different information https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/parent-grandparent-super-visa/eligibility.html

Comment: That's super visa.

Comment: yes that's what I had asked in the question as well :) so for that, it should be relatively quick right? I don't have to wait too long?

Comment: You did mention about PR in your first comment so the rest of the comments were relating for PR. You can check every application's average processing time [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/check-processing-times.html) If my answer has answered your original question, you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer.

Comment: @DipenShah I think you misread the first comment.  Mayooran asked how long "before I can sponsor her with my PR" not "sponsor her *for* PR."  That is, to paraphrase, "after becoming a PR, how long before I can sponsor her for a super visa?"